# Why the color miss match

Tags: materials

Im with wip of Chick. Add hair particles and texture. The body and the wings particles and texture are same. Why the wing have little blackish color on it. Its not similar like body and head. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: How does it look like without the PS? (don't imagine a second I want to see a naked chick, this is just a technical question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are the same on the whole body, but there are much more hairs on the wings, thats why it looks darker. Probably the vert density isn't even on the whole mesh and that causes the uneven hair count. Try to modifiy the advenced settings.

[image]

Comment: cool tip. Thanks